# Find first occurrence of consecutive start / end columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table containing dates of employment. A new row is added every time a change happens - a change in salary being the most common one. So the new row would equal said person's last TO-date plus one (1). If my salary changed 2014-04-01 my previous row would end its `TO` date in `2013-03-31` and my new row would begin its `FROM` date with `2014-04-01`.

I want to get the **date of employment** only, not the ones that follows due to changes. Have a look at this table:

```
SSN         FROM        TO
----------------------------------
0987654321  2011-01-01  2011-12-31
0987654321  2012-01-01  2012-12-31
1234567890  2012-01-01  2012-12-31
0987654321  2013-01-01  2013-12-31
1234567890  2013-01-01  2013-06-30
0987654321  2014-01-01  2014-08-31
1234567890  2016-01-01  2016-12-31
1234567890  2017-01-01  2017-12-31
1234567890  2018-01-01  null
```

The output I want:

```
SSN         FROM        TO
----------------------------------
0987654321  2011-01-01  2014-08-31
1234567890  2012-01-01  2013-06-30
1234567890  2016-01-01  null
```

Thought I could create a field that equals one more day than `TO`:

```
SELECT 
    SSN, TO, FROM, DATEADD(DAY, 1, TO) AS NEW 
FROM 
    table
```

But I have no idea how I'd go on matching `NEW` with `TO` on different rows. Perhaps `WHERE NOT EXISTS` or something? I can't make it work.

Then I thought I could use `LAG` but the previous row in the table is not related to the next row by default, and I couldn't use `ORDER BY` in a subquery. I doesn't allow it, don't know why (T-SQL?).

FYI, I can't `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT INTO TABLE` etc, and I can't declare variables either. We will get a module that allows all of that, but for now I don't have those privileges.

**Update:**
The first answer was actually correct, but I noticed another field that interferes with it. One SSN can contain several ID's, so the ID's have to be split as well. Here's actual data from my table.

```
CREATE TABLE Samples
    (
     SSN varchar(10), 
     ID varchar(4),
     FromDate Date, 
     ToDate Date
    );

INSERT INTO Samples
(SSN, ID, FromDate, ToDate)
VALUES
( '6612140000', '1000', '2005-01-01', '2005-03-31' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2005-04-01', '2005-09-30' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2005-10-01', '2006-03-31' ), 
( '6612140000', '2000', '2005-10-01', '2006-04-30' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2006-04-01', '2007-03-31' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2007-04-01', '2008-03-31' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2008-04-01', '2009-03-31' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2009-04-01', '2010-03-31' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2010-04-01', '2010-11-30' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2010-12-01', '2011-03-31' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2011-04-01', '2011-08-21' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2011-08-22', '2011-11-13' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2011-11-14', '2011-11-30' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2011-12-01', '2012-01-31' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2016-07-01', '2017-03-31' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2017-04-01', '2017-11-30' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2017-12-01', '2018-03-31' ),
( '6612140000', '1000', '2018-04-01', null ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2013-11-01', '2013-11-30' ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2013-12-01', '2013-12-31' ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2014-01-01', '2014-03-31' ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2014-04-01', '2014-12-31' ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2015-05-01', '2015-05-31' ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2015-06-01', '2015-09-30' ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2015-10-01', '2015-10-31' ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2016-01-25', '2016-07-24' ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2016-07-25', '2016-08-31' ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2016-09-01', '2017-03-31' ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2017-04-01', '2017-11-30' ),
( '7605140000', '1000', '2017-12-01', null );
```

And the code from the answer, that I tried adding the `ID` field to, without luck:

```
with

  FromDates as (
    -- All of the   FromDates   for each   SSN   for which there is not
    --   a contiguous preceding period.
    select SO.SSN, SO.ID, SO.FromDate, SO.ToDate,
      Row_Number() over ( partition by SO.SSN order by SO.FromDate ) as RN
      from Samples as SO
      where not exists (
        select 42 from Samples as SI where SI.SSN = SO.SSN and SI.ID = SO.ID and
          SI.ToDate = DateAdd( day, -1, SO.FromDate ) ) ),

  ToDates as (
    -- All of the   ToDates   for each   SSN   for which there is not
    --   a contiguous following period.
    select SSN, ID, FromDate, ToDate, Row_Number() over ( partition by SSN order by FromDate ) as RN
      from Samples as SO
      where not exists (
        select 42 from Samples as SI where SI.SSN = SO.SSN and SI.ID = SO.ID and
          SI.FromDate = DateAdd( day, 1, SO.ToDate ) ) ),

  Ranges as (
    -- Pair the   FromDate   and   ToDate   entries for each   SSN .
    select F.SSN, F.ID, F.FromDate, T.ToDate
      from FromDates as F inner join
        ToDates as T on T.SSN = F.SSN and T.ID = F.ID and T.RN = F.RN ) 

-- Use any ONE of the following   select   statements to see what is going on:
-- select * from FromDates
--  select * from ToDates
  select * from Ranges 
  -- where SSN = '6612140000'
  order by SSN, ID, FromDate
```

Returns:

```
SSN         ID      FromDate    ToDate
6612140000  1000    2016-07-01  (null)
7605140000  1000    2013-11-01  2014-12-31
7605140000  1000    2014-03-01  2014-12-31
7605140000  1000    2015-05-01  2015-10-31
7605140000  1000    2015-05-01  2015-10-31
7605140000  1000    2016-01-25  (null)
```

Comment: Your sample data contains both duplicate and overlapping ranges, e.g. `( '7605140000', '1000', '2014-03-01', '2014-12-31' )` and `( '7605140000', '1000', '2014-04-01', '2014-12-31' )`. Is this correct or is your actual data clean (which simplifies the query)?

Comment: @dnoeth nicely spotted. I made a boo boo. I have now removed the faulty rows for that SSN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example assembles the islands from your data. By changing which of the final `select` statements is enabled/commented you can see the intermediate results in the process.

**Update**: Changed the date comparisons in the CTE so that they can benefit from indexes on `SSN, FromDate` and `SSN, ToDate`.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples table ( SSN VarChar(10), FromDate Date, ToDate Date );
insert into @Samples ( SSN, FromDate, ToDate ) values
  ( '0987654321', '2011-01-01', '2011-12-31' ),
  ( '0987654321', '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31' ),
  ( '1234567890', '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31' ),
  ( '0987654321', '2013-01-01', '2013-12-31' ),
  ( '1234567890', '2013-01-01', '2013-06-30' ),
  ( '0987654321', '2014-01-01', '2014-08-31' ),
  ( '1234567890', '2016-01-01', '2016-12-31' ),
  ( '1234567890', '2017-01-01', '2017-12-31' ),
  ( '1234567890', '2018-01-01', null );
select *
  from @Samples;

-- Sample data made a little easier to read.
select *,
  case when exists (
    select 42 from @Samples as SI where SI.SSN = S.SSN and
      DateDiff( day, S.ToDate, SI.FromDate ) = 1 ) then 1 else 0 end as Continued
  from @Samples as S
  order by SSN, FromDate;

-- Process the data.
with
  FromDates as (
    -- All of the   FromDates   for each   SSN   for which there is not
    --   a contiguous preceding period.
    select SO.SSN, SO.FromDate, SO.ToDate,
      Row_Number() over ( partition by SO.SSN order by SO.FromDate ) as RN
      from @Samples as SO
      where not exists (
        select 42 from @Samples as SI where SI.SSN = SO.SSN and
          SI.ToDate = DateAdd( day, -1, SO.FromDate ) ) ),
  ToDates as (
    -- All of the   ToDates   for each   SSN   for which there is not
    --   a contiguous following period.
    select SSN, FromDate, ToDate, Row_Number() over ( partition by SSN order by FromDate ) as RN
      from @Samples as SO
      where not exists (
        select 42 from @Samples as SI where SI.SSN = SO.SSN and
          SI.FromDate = DateAdd( day, 1, SO.ToDate ) ) ),
  Ranges as (
    -- Pair the   FromDate   and   ToDate   entries for each   SSN .
    select F.SSN, F.FromDate, T.ToDate
      from FromDates as F inner join
        ToDates as T on T.SSN = F.SSN and T.RN = F.RN )
  -- Use any ONE of the following   select   statements to see what is going on:
--  select * from FromDates order by SSN, FromDate;
--  select * from ToDates order by SSN, FromDate;
  select * from Ranges order by SSN, FromDate;
```

Of course, if there were actually separate `Id` values within `SSN`s that were to be treated independently, the answer would change to something like this:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( SSN VarChar(10), Id VarChar(4), FromDate Date, ToDate Date );
insert into @Samples ( SSN, ID, FromDate, ToDate ) values
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2005-01-01', '2005-03-31' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2005-04-01', '2005-09-30' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2005-10-01', '2006-03-31' ), 
    ( '6612140000', '2000', '2005-10-01', '2006-04-30' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2006-04-01', '2007-03-31' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2007-04-01', '2008-03-31' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2008-04-01', '2009-03-31' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2009-04-01', '2010-03-31' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2010-04-01', '2010-11-30' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2010-12-01', '2011-03-31' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2011-04-01', '2011-08-21' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2011-08-22', '2011-11-13' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2011-11-14', '2011-11-30' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2011-12-01', '2012-01-31' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2016-07-01', '2017-03-31' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2017-04-01', '2017-11-30' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2017-12-01', '2018-03-31' ),
    ( '6612140000', '1000', '2018-04-01', null ),
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2013-11-01', '2013-11-30' ),
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2013-12-01', '2013-12-31' ),
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2014-01-01', '2014-03-31' ),
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2014-03-01', '2014-12-31' ),
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2014-04-01', '2014-12-31' ),
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2015-05-01', '2015-05-31' ),
--  ( '7605140000', '1000', '2015-05-01', '2015-05-31' ), -- Duplicate row?!
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2015-06-01', '2015-09-30' ),
--  ( '7605140000', '1000', '2015-06-01', '2015-09-30' ), -- Duplicate row?!
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2015-10-01', '2015-10-31' ),
--  ( '7605140000', '1000', '2015-10-01', '2015-10-31' ), -- Duplicate row?!
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2016-01-25', '2016-07-24' ),
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2016-07-25', '2016-08-31' ),
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2016-09-01', '2017-03-31' ),
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2017-04-01', '2017-11-30' ),
    ( '7605140000', '1000', '2017-12-01', null );
select *
  from @Samples;

-- Sample data made a little easier to read.
select *,
  case when exists (
    select 42 from @Samples as SI where SI.SSN = S.SSN and SI.Id = S.Id and
      DateDiff( day, S.ToDate, SI.FromDate ) = 1 ) then 1 else 0 end as Continued
  from @Samples as S
  order by SSN, Id, FromDate;

-- Process the data.
with
  FromDates as (
    -- All of the   FromDates   for each   SSN   for which there is not
    --   a contiguous preceding period.
    select SO.SSN, SO.Id, SO.FromDate, SO.ToDate,
      Row_Number() over ( partition by SO.SSN, SO.Id order by SO.FromDate ) as RN
      from @Samples as SO
      where not exists (
        select 42 from @Samples as SI where SI.SSN = SO.SSN and SI.Id = SO.Id and
          SI.ToDate = DateAdd( day, -1, SO.FromDate ) ) ),
  ToDates as (
    -- All of the   ToDates   for each   SSN   for which there is not
    --   a contiguous following period.
    select SO.SSN, SO.Id, SO.FromDate, SO.ToDate,
      Row_Number() over ( partition by SSN, SO.Id order by FromDate ) as RN
      from @Samples as SO
      where not exists (
        select 42 from @Samples as SI where SI.SSN = SO.SSN and SI.Id = SO.Id and
          SI.FromDate = DateAdd( day, 1, SO.ToDate ) ) ),
  Ranges as (
    -- Pair the   FromDate   and   ToDate   entries for each   SSN .
    select F.SSN, F.Id, F.FromDate, T.ToDate
      from FromDates as F inner join
        ToDates as T on T.SSN = F.SSN and T.Id = F.Id and T.RN = F.RN )
  -- Use any ONE of the following   select   statements to see what is going on:
--  select * from FromDates order by SSN, Id, FromDate;
--  select * from ToDates order by SSN, Id, FromDate;
  select * from Ranges order by SSN, Id, FromDate;
```

Comment: Very nice. It seems to work but I get 3 rows in FromDates, 4 rows in ToDates and 3 rows in Ranges - when looking at SSN 1234567890. Therefor the ToDate doesn't make sense when using your `select * from Ranges`. Any ideas?

Comment: @TAKL I'm getting back three rows from each part of the CTE, one row for `SSN` "0987654321" and two for "1234567890". Are you using the same set of sample data? (I used the posted code and discovered a missing parenthesis from my update. It caused a syntax error, not incorrect results. Fixed. Also tested more edge cases, e.g. an `SSN` with only one row having a NULL `ToDate`.)

Comment: You are certainly correct. I mixed up the ToDates/FromDates selects. It did work. But I also messed up with my original table, since it shows that there's an ID field that interferes with your answer. One SSN can have several ID's and I can't get the correct response because of this. I hope you can help me with the last piece as well, although your answer is already correct regarding to the original question.

Comment: Please see the second answer in the answer for the answer to the question you've chosen to ask instead of the question you asked. (Huh?) I took the liberty of ignoring the duplicate rows in the New & Improved sample data, or my eyes were getting crossed as it's getting late here.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! You are a life saver / lightsaber.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps & islands problem, a standard solution is based on nested Analytical functions:

#1: Compare each row to the previous row and flag it with 1 when a new group starts.

#2: Calculate a cumulative sum over the flag to assign a number to each group of rows.

#3: Now you can do whatever you want with those groups.

```
-- data must be correct, i.e. a Slowly Changing Dimension without gaps or overlapping periods
with calcFlag as
 (
   select SSN, Id, FromDate, ToDate,
      -- new group starts when the previous end date
      -- is not the current start date -1
      case when lag(ToDate)
                over (partition by SSN, Id
                      order by FromDate ) = DateAdd( day, -1, FromDate )
           then 0
           else 1
      end as flag
   from samples
 ),
calcGroup as 
 (
   select SSN, Id, FromDate, ToDate, flag,
      -- Cumulative Sum to dynamically assign group number
      sum(flag)
      over ( partition by SSN, Id 
             order by FromDate 
             rows unbounded preceding ) as grp#
   from calcFlag
 )
select SSN, Id, 
   min(FromDate), 
   -- either max date or NULL 
   nullif(max(coalesce(ToDate, '9999-12-31')), '9999-12-31')
from calcGroup
group by SSN, Id, grp# -- include dynamically calculated group number
order by SSN, Id, min(FromDate)
;
```